# Correct way to formulate media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

While learning about media queries I often find two different ways of calling on these:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 768px) {
}
```

And

```
 @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 768px) {
    }
```

Most of the info I found was on the 'min-device-width' being the "correct" one, however when I just tried to implement it in my code, the 'min-device-width' did not work and the 'min-width' did. In the demos both work, but in theory I seem to be needing one or the other.

Why is this, and what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are valid media queries, but with different outcomes:

`min-device-width` refers to the width of the device

`min-width` refers to the width of the browser window (including the scroll bar!) and may therefore be smaller than `min-device-width`, as the browser doesn't necessarily covers the whole screen

edit: There are many more media queries (e.g. `width` for an exact width), but `min-width` and `max-width` are probably the most important ones for responsive design.

Comment: Is that the reason why 'min-device-width' does not work, because I'm scaling my browser to see what it does? How about dev tools like the one in Safari, that simulate smaller screens/browsers?

Comment: @Kelly by using those browser tools.. media query will treat it that device. means, min-**device** will work there.

Comment: @Kelly as written above you won't be able to reproduce min-device-width by using developer tools, as it's about the width of your decive (hardware!), which you obviously cannot resize. If your question is answered, feel free to accept the answer  / close it.